# React app deployed version is showing blank but development is working fine

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-router, github-pages

developed a small react app to be my project portfolio but when i deployed it using gh-pages it isn't showing anything on the browser. All is blank. But locally, using npm start, it works 100%

i dont see any errors on browser or vscode console

thank you!

This is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <title>Rui Melo's Portfolio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

this is my App.js file

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Homepage from './pages/Homepage'
import Projects from './pages/Projects'

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Homepage />} />
      <Route path='/projects' element={<Projects />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}

export default App
```

this is my index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter basename="/">
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "homepage": ".",
  "name": "portfolio1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding "homepage": "https://username.github.io/reponame"
in your package.json?

Comment: yeah, it didn't work either